# bat script gives the wrong values of free space

Tags: batch-file

i have bat script that check the free space out of the total amount, but the numbers that it gives me are not the same as windows shows

this is the script:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=D:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)

@echo off
SET /a diskused=%disktotal:~0,-9% - %diskavail:~0,-9%
ECHO(143,Volume %volume%,%disktotal:~0,-9% GB, %diskavail:~0,-9% GB  > disk_usage.txt
SET "volume=C:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)

SET /a diskused=%disktotal:~0,-9% - %diskavail:~0,-9%
ECHO(143,Volume %volume%,%disktotal:~0,-9% GB, %diskavail:~0,-9% GB  >> disk_usage.txt
```

the output is:

```
143,Volume D:, 655 GB,  239 GB  
143,Volume C:, 63 GB,  26 GB
```

but the windows shows :

```
c 24.3 free out of 59.4 GB
D 223 GB free out of 610 GB
```

why does that happen? is it because of the diff between GB as 1000 MB vs gibibyte 1024^3?
and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: Your question does not really make any sense, it seems as if you're basing your opinion of 'wrong' upon the figures returned as output from 'the windows', _(whatever that means)_. In order for us to determine if your calculations are correct, it would make more sense if you were to provide within your question content the actual output from `fsutil volume diskfree C:`.

Comment: Since you seem to know the difference between Gigabytes and Gibibytes, why don't you just do the byte value conversion manually, then you'd find out if the returned values match…

Comment: Drive manufacturers use decimal _(base 10)_ bytes when selling their drives, but Windows still uses binary bytes _(base 2)_. The confusing thing is that the term GB is used by both, even though Windows should probably use the term GiB instead. _So a disk drive sold at 1TB/1000GB will show in Windows at around 931GB, because it is technically 930 GiB (1 GiB = 1.073741824 GB; 1 GB = 0.93132257461548 GiB)_. That means the figures you're wanting to output to the text file, and showing against the term GB, will technically be GiB too, although will probably be harmless written as GB.

Comment: @aschipfl, after I posted the question I did that, and indeed the dif, was because of that, so on my PostgreSQL that use the data I did the calculation manually

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of one way of doing the task you've shown quickly from a batch file. It gets another scripting language do all of the work instead:

```sh
<!-- :
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" 1>"disk_usage.txt"
@GoTo :EOF
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each Drv In o.Drives:If Drv.IsReady=True Then
  WScript.Echo "143,Volume "&Drv.DriveLetter&":,"&_
  Round(Drv.TotalSize/1073741824,1)&" GB,"&_
  Round(Drv.FreeSpace/1073741824,1)&" GB"
End If:Next
</Script></Job>
```